# WPF: mouse leave event doesn't trigger with mouse down

Tags: wpf, events, mouse

I'm having an issue with mouse enter / leave events. When mouse button is pressed and hold with cursor inside the control and then cursor is moved out of the control fast enough this events don't trigger.

Could you please advice me why it happens? Is there any way to obtain these events properly?

Please check the sample project to see it in action: https://www.dropbox.com/s/w5ra2vzegjtauso/SampleApp.zip

**Update.** I have found the same problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3797844/wpf-mousedown-no-mouseleave-event?rq=1) without an answer. Started bounty there.

Comment: I can only guess at this point, but i would say that when you click, WPF gets a mouse capture for the button, which works a bit differently. So while pressed, you don't leave the control. But you said "moved fast enough" if thats really the case, than i guess i'm heading in the wrong direction.

Comment: Am on Windows-8 and I tried your Sample. It works fine. However if I add a TextBox to the StackPanel, click inside it and move out, Events do not get triggered since the TextBox marks RoutedEvents as handled and does not release until the MouseUp. If I then then add a listener to force receiving updates say like `text.AddHandler(MouseMoveEvent, new MouseEventHandler(Window_MouseMove), true);` I get the mouse move calls. Does not work for Enter and Leave though. You might have to check cursor position to window co-ords in MouseMove and explicitly call LostFocus on such Controls.

Comment: I can reproduce this (the sample app works well for that, but tested it in my own as well), and speed _does_ matter. @Idsa: is your problem restricted to leaving the window, or is it also about leaving controls within the window?

Comment: @adabyron, currently - a control inside a window. But it would be interesting to find out a solution for a window itself too.

Comment: Issue reproduced for window. A simple workaround would be to hook mouse move event at low level and check position against Window position and size.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

EDIT: After Sisyphe correctly noted that the behavior did not work for elements with mouse interaction, I have rewritten the code.

The behavior can be attached to a window or any other FrameworkElement. By default, all contained elements will be monitored for MouseLeave while the left mouse button is down, and the handlers executed. The behavior can also be applied just to its associated element by setting `MonitorSubControls="False"`.

What the behavior does, basically (refer to the comments in the code for more detail):

- Is only "active" if left mouse button is pressed
- Watches for mouse position changes from in- to outside of an element. In this case, executes the event handlers.

Known limitations (could all be resolved with some more effort, I reckon, but don't seem too important to me):

- Does not execute handlers for transitions to a contained element ("inner" boundaries)
- Does not guarantee correct order of execution of the handlers
- Does not resolve that for slow transitions to the outside of the window, e.LeftButton is reported as released (bug?).
- I decided not to use the Win32 hook and instead using a timer, who will not fire more than about every 0.15 seconds (despite a smaller interval set, clock drift?). For fast mouse movements, the evaluated points could be too far apart and miss an element that is just flitted across.

[image]

This script produces the output below: With the behavior attached to the window, moving inside the orangeBorder (leaves blueBorder by inner boundary with mouse button released: 0), pressing left mousebutton inside the orange border and moving (fast) outside the window executes the leave handlers (1 - 4). Releasing the mouse button outside the window, moving back in over the goldTextBox (5), pressing left mousebutton in the textbox, leaving (fast or slow) outside the window again executes the correct handlers (6 - 9).

[image]

Xaml (example):

```xml
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MouseLeaveControlWindow"
            xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
            xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
            xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"
            xmlns:beh="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1.Behavior"
            Title="MouseLeaveControlWindow" Height="300" Width="300" x:Name="window" MouseLeave="OnMouseLeave">
    <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
        <beh:MonitorMouseLeaveBehavior />
    </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
    <Grid x:Name="grid" MouseLeave="OnMouseLeave" Background="Transparent">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Border x:Name="blueBorder" MouseLeave="OnMouseLeave" Background="SteelBlue" Margin="50" Grid.RowSpan="2" />
        <Border x:Name="orangeBorder" MouseLeave="OnMouseLeave"  Background="DarkOrange" Margin="70, 70, 70, 20" />
        <TextBox x:Name="goldTextBox" MouseLeave="OnMouseLeave" Background="Gold" Margin="70, 20, 70, 70" Grid.Row="1" Text="I'm a TextBox" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Code behind (just for debug purpose):

```cs
public partial class MouseLeaveControlWindow : Window
{
    public MouseLeaveControlWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private int i = 0;
    private void OnMouseLeave(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        FrameworkElement fe = (FrameworkElement)sender;
        if (e.LeftButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(string.Format("{0}: Left {1}.", i, fe.Name)); i++;
        }
        else
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(string.Format("{0}: Left {1} (Released).", i, fe.Name)); i++;
        }
    }
}
```

MonitorMouseLeaveBehavior:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Timers;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Interactivity;
using System.Windows.Interop;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Windows.Media;
using WpfApplication1.Helpers;

namespace WpfApplication1.Behavior
{
    public class MonitorMouseLeaveBehavior : Behavior<FrameworkElement>
    {
        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
        internal static extern bool GetCursorPos(ref Win32Point pt);

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        internal struct Win32Point
        {
            public Int32 X;
            public Int32 Y;
        };

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        public static extern short GetAsyncKeyState(UInt16 virtualKeyCode);

        private enum VK
        {
            LBUTTON = 0x01
        }

        private bool _tracking;
        private const int _interval = 1;
        private Timer _checkPosTimer = new Timer(_interval);
        private Dictionary<FrameworkElement, RoutedEventHandlerInfo[]> _leaveHandlersForElement = new Dictionary<FrameworkElement, RoutedEventHandlerInfo[]>();
        private Window _window;
        private Dictionary<FrameworkElement, Rect> _boundsByElement = new Dictionary<FrameworkElement, Rect>();
        private Dictionary<FrameworkElement, bool> _wasInside = new Dictionary<FrameworkElement, bool>();
        private List<FrameworkElement> _elements = new List<FrameworkElement>();


        /// <summary>
        /// If true, all subcontrols are monitored for the mouseleave event when left mousebutton is down.
        /// True by default.
        /// </summary>
        public bool MonitorSubControls { get { return (bool)GetValue(MonitorSubControlsProperty); } set { SetValue(MonitorSubControlsProperty, value); } }
        public static readonly DependencyProperty MonitorSubControlsProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("MonitorSubControls", typeof(bool), typeof(MonitorMouseLeaveBehavior), new PropertyMetadata(true, OnMonitorSubControlsChanged));

        private static void OnMonitorSubControlsChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            MonitorMouseLeaveBehavior beh = (MonitorMouseLeaveBehavior)d;
            beh.AddOrRemoveLogicalChildren((bool)e.NewValue);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Initial actions
        /// </summary>
        protected override void OnAttached()
        {
            _window = this.AssociatedObject is Window ? (Window)this.AssociatedObject : Window.GetWindow(this.AssociatedObject); // get window
            _window.SourceInitialized += (s, e) =>
            {
                this.AddOrRemoveLogicalChildren(this.MonitorSubControls); // get all monitored elements
                this.AttachHandlers(true); // attach mousedown and sizechanged handlers
                this.GetAllBounds(); // determine bounds of all elements
                _checkPosTimer.Elapsed += (s1, e1) => Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)(() => { CheckPosition(); }));
            };
            base.OnAttached();
        }

        protected override void OnDetaching()
        {
            this.AttachHandlers(false);
            base.OnDetaching();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Starts or stops monitoring of the AssociatedObject's logical children.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="add"></param>
        private void AddOrRemoveLogicalChildren(bool add)
        {
            if (_window != null && _window.IsInitialized)
            {
                AddOrRemoveSizeChangedHandlers(false);
                _elements.Clear();
                if (add)
                    _elements.AddRange(VisualHelper.FindLogicalChildren<FrameworkElement>(this.AssociatedObject));
                _elements.Add(this.AssociatedObject);
                AddOrRemoveSizeChangedHandlers(true);
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Attaches/detaches size changed handlers to the monitored elements
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="add"></param>
        private void AddOrRemoveSizeChangedHandlers(bool add)
        {
            foreach (var element in _elements)
            {
                element.SizeChanged -= element_SizeChanged;
                if (add) element.SizeChanged += element_SizeChanged;
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Adjusts the stored bounds to the changed size
        /// </summary>
        void element_SizeChanged(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            FrameworkElement fe = sender as FrameworkElement;
            if (fe != null)
                GetBounds(fe);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Attaches/Detaches MouseLeftButtonDown and SizeChanged handlers 
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="attach">true: attach, false: detach</param>
        private void AttachHandlers(bool attach)
        {
            AddOrRemoveSizeChangedHandlers(attach);

            if (attach)
                _window.PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown += window_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown;
            else // detach
                _window.PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown -= window_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets the bounds for all monitored elements
        /// </summary>
        private void GetAllBounds()
        {
            _boundsByElement.Clear();
            foreach (var element in _elements)
                GetBounds(element);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets the bounds of the control, which are used to check if the mouse position
        /// is located within. Note that this only covers rectangular control shapes.
        /// </summary>
        private void GetBounds(FrameworkElement element)
        {
            Point p1 = new Point(0, 0);
            Point p2 = new Point(element.ActualWidth, element.ActualHeight);
            p1 = element.TransformToVisual(_window).Transform(p1);
            p2 = element.TransformToVisual(_window).Transform(p2);

            if (element == _window) // window bounds need to account for the border
            {
                var titleHeight = SystemParameters.WindowCaptionHeight + 2 * SystemParameters.ResizeFrameHorizontalBorderHeight; //  not sure about that one
                var verticalBorderWidth = SystemParameters.ResizeFrameVerticalBorderWidth;
                p1.Offset(-verticalBorderWidth, -titleHeight);
                p2.Offset(-verticalBorderWidth, -titleHeight);
            }

            Rect bounds = new Rect(p1, p2);

            if (_boundsByElement.ContainsKey(element))
                _boundsByElement[element] = bounds;
            else
                _boundsByElement.Add(element, bounds);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// For all monitored elements, detach the MouseLeave event handlers and store them locally,
        /// to be executed manually.
        /// </summary>
        private void RerouteLeaveHandlers()
        {
            foreach (var element in _elements)
            {
                if (!_leaveHandlersForElement.ContainsKey(element))
                {
                    var handlers = ReflectionHelper.GetRoutedEventHandlers(element, UIElement.MouseLeaveEvent);
                    if (handlers != null)
                    {
                        _leaveHandlersForElement.Add(element, handlers);
                        foreach (var handler in handlers)
                            element.MouseLeave -= (MouseEventHandler)handler.Handler; // detach handlers
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Reattach all leave handlers that were detached in window_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown.
        /// </summary>
        private void ReattachLeaveHandlers()
        {
            foreach (var kvp in _leaveHandlersForElement)
            {
                FrameworkElement fe = kvp.Key;
                foreach (var handler in kvp.Value)
                {
                    if (handler.Handler is MouseEventHandler)
                        fe.MouseLeave += (MouseEventHandler)handler.Handler;
                }
            }

            _leaveHandlersForElement.Clear();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Checks if the mouse position is inside the bounds of the elements
        /// If there is a transition from inside to outside, the leave event handlers are executed
        /// </summary>
        private void DetermineIsInside()
        {
            Point p = _window.PointFromScreen(GetMousePosition());
            foreach (var element in _elements)
            {
                if (_boundsByElement.ContainsKey(element))
                {
                    bool isInside = _boundsByElement[element].Contains(p);
                    bool wasInside = _wasInside.ContainsKey(element) && _wasInside[element];

                    if (wasInside && !isInside)
                        ExecuteLeaveHandlers(element);

                    if (_wasInside.ContainsKey(element))
                        _wasInside[element] = isInside;
                    else
                        _wasInside.Add(element, isInside);
                }
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets the mouse position relative to the screen
        /// </summary>
        public static Point GetMousePosition()
        {
            Win32Point w32Mouse = new Win32Point();
            GetCursorPos(ref w32Mouse);
            return new Point(w32Mouse.X, w32Mouse.Y);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets the mouse button state. MouseEventArgs.LeftButton is notoriously unreliable.
        /// </summary>
        private bool IsMouseLeftButtonPressed()
        {
            short leftMouseKeyState = GetAsyncKeyState((ushort)VK.LBUTTON);
            bool ispressed = leftMouseKeyState < 0;

            return ispressed;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Executes the leave handlers that were attached to the controls.
        /// They have been detached previously by this behavior (see window_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown), to prevent double execution.
        /// After mouseup, they are reattached (see CheckPosition)
        /// </summary>
        private void ExecuteLeaveHandlers(FrameworkElement fe)
        {
            MouseDevice mouseDev = InputManager.Current.PrimaryMouseDevice;
            MouseEventArgs mouseEvent = new MouseEventArgs(mouseDev, 0) { RoutedEvent = Control.MouseLeaveEvent };

            if (_leaveHandlersForElement.ContainsKey(fe))
            {
                foreach (var handler in _leaveHandlersForElement[fe])
                {
                    if (handler.Handler is MouseEventHandler)
                        ((MouseEventHandler)handler.Handler).Invoke(fe, mouseEvent);
                }
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Sets the mouse capture (events outside the window are still directed to it),
        /// and tells the behavior to watch out for a missed leave event
        /// </summary>
        private void window_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("--- left mousebutton down ---"); // todo remove

            this.RerouteLeaveHandlers();
            _tracking = true;
            _checkPosTimer.Start();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Uses the _tracking field as well as left mouse button state to determine if either 
        /// leave event handlers should be executed, or monitoring should be stopped.
        /// </summary>
        private void CheckPosition()
        {
            if (_tracking)
            {
                if (IsMouseLeftButtonPressed())
                {
                    this.DetermineIsInside();
                }
                else
                {
                    _wasInside.Clear();
                    _tracking = false;
                    _checkPosTimer.Stop();
                    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("--- left mousebutton up ---"); // todo remove

                    // invoking ReattachLeaveHandlers() immediately would rethrow MouseLeave for top grid/window 
                    // if both a) mouse is outside window and b) mouse moves. Wait with reattach until mouse is inside window again and moves.
                    _window.MouseMove += ReattachHandler; 
                }
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Handles the first _window.MouseMove event after left mouse button was released,
        /// and reattaches the MouseLeaveHandlers. Detaches itself to be executed only once.
        /// </summary>
        private void ReattachHandler(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            ReattachLeaveHandlers();
            _window.MouseMove -= ReattachHandler; // only once
        }
    }
}
```

VisualHelper.FindLogicalChildren, ReflectionHelper.[GetRoutedEventHandlers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9436960/385995):

```
public static List<T> FindLogicalChildren<T>(DependencyObject obj) where T : DependencyObject
{
    List<T> children = new List<T>();
    foreach (var child in LogicalTreeHelper.GetChildren(obj))
    {
        if (child != null)
        {
            if (child is T)
                children.Add((T)child);

            if (child is DependencyObject)
                children.AddRange(FindLogicalChildren<T>((DependencyObject)child)); // recursive
        }
    }
    return children;
}
/// <summary>
/// Gets the list of routed event handlers subscribed to the specified routed event.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="element">The UI element on which the event is defined.</param>
/// <param name="routedEvent">The routed event for which to retrieve the event handlers.</param>
/// <returns>The list of subscribed routed event handlers.</returns>
public static RoutedEventHandlerInfo[] GetRoutedEventHandlers(UIElement element, RoutedEvent routedEvent)
{
    var routedEventHandlers = default(RoutedEventHandlerInfo[]);
    // Get the EventHandlersStore instance which holds event handlers for the specified element.
    // The EventHandlersStore class is declared as internal.
    var eventHandlersStoreProperty = typeof(UIElement).GetProperty("EventHandlersStore", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
    object eventHandlersStore = eventHandlersStoreProperty.GetValue(element, null);

    if (eventHandlersStore != null)
    {
        // Invoke the GetRoutedEventHandlers method on the EventHandlersStore instance 
        // for getting an array of the subscribed event handlers.
        var getRoutedEventHandlers = eventHandlersStore.GetType().GetMethod("GetRoutedEventHandlers", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
        routedEventHandlers = (RoutedEventHandlerInfo[])getRoutedEventHandlers.Invoke(eventHandlersStore, new object[] { routedEvent });
    }
    return routedEventHandlers;
}
```

Comment: Working partially for me. It's okay as long as the MouseDown was made on a control that does not have any mouse interraction. But if you click on a Control like TextBox, or TabItem for example, the issue remains (this must be due to the workaround relying on a MouseCapture)

Comment: Yes, that is unfortunately true. I'm not sure it has got to do with Capture, I'd guess it's more about Focus, but there is definitely a problem. Actually more than one, as one is easily remedied, by using PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown instead of MouseLeftButtonDown. I'll report back later.

Comment: I have edited the post to accomodate mouse interactive controls. The behavior now also monitors all logical children of the element it is attached to.

Answer (score 5):

**Approach #1** - is still a valid one (as a pure managed solution) if you work out the specifics.
(capture could be given to a specific control to avoid issues, but I haven't tried)

This should help you get the events ('fixed' events).

Key is to track the mouse move when outside window (and only when mouse is down).

For that you'd need to do the `capture` (but slightly different than suggested as that won't work - on down/up instead).

```
private void Window_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    this.CaptureMouse();
}
private void Window_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    this.ReleaseMouseCapture();
}
private void Window_MouseLeave(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    test1.Content = "Mouse left";
}
private void Window_MouseEnter(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    test1.Content = "Mouse entered";
}
private void Window_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (Mouse.Captured == this)
    {
        if (!this.IsMouseInBounds(e))
            Window_MouseLeave(sender, e);
        else
            Window_MouseEnter(sender, e);
    }
    test2.Content = e.GetPosition(this).ToString();
}
private bool IsMouseInBounds(MouseEventArgs e)
{
    var client = ((FrameworkElement)this.Content);
    Rect bounds = new Rect(0, 0, client.ActualWidth, client.ActualHeight);
    return bounds.Contains(e.GetPosition(this));
}
private Point GetRealPosition(Point mousePoint)
{
    return Application.Current.MainWindow.PointFromScreen(mousePoint);
}
```

Note:
You'd need to finish this according to your situation. I have just 'dummy wired' the mouse move to `Enter` and `Leave` and w/o any smart algorithm there (i.e. `generated` enter/leave will keep on firing). I.e. add some flag to actually save the `state` of the enter/leave properly.

Also I'm measuring whether mouse is within the 'client bounds' of the Window. You'd need to adjust that if you need that in respect of borders etc.

Also I forgot to add the obvious - wire up the new events `MouseDown="Window_MouseDown" MouseUp="Window_MouseUp"`

Answer (score 3):

That's "normal" behaviour. Capture the mouse inside MouseEnter handler.

```
Mouse.Capture(yourUIElement);
```

and later release it in MouseLeave,

```
Mouse.Capture(null);
```

Edited: More explanation.
WPF does not track mouse movement precisely. You can deduce that from the fact that if you capture MouseMove event, you can see that the it reports you event every 20milliseconds intervals and not by pixel precision.. more like 8 pixels per event.

Now this is not that horrible, but WPF also does not report mouse movement outside the window, if you happen to move your mouse. This is default behaviour. You can change it throuh Mouse.Capture as said.

Now, you can imagine why this problem happens. If you can move your mouse outside the window faster than mouse move report happens, then WPF still thinks that it's inside the application.

Comment: How could this be normal behavior ? Speed at wich the mouse is moved outside the window impacts the trigger of the MouseLeave event (if it's too fast, it does not trigger.) For me, it's everything but normal.

Comment: By normal I mean't, it's not a bug. It works like it was designed. I've added little explanation

Answer (score 3):

#### EDIT

> In case you need it - I edited in **a simplified wrapper for ease of use** (just add commands in your
>   view-model)

**Approach #2** - using Global Mouse Hook to track mouse move - the rest is similar to #1.
Actually, this is more of an example on how to do a global hook from C#.

---

In XAML you can hook up all 3 or just one, two events

```
my:Hooks.EnterCommand="{Binding EnterCommand}"
my:Hooks.LeaveCommand="{Binding LeaveCommand}"
my:Hooks.MouseMoveCommand="{Binding MoveCommand}"
```

In your view-model define commands

```
RelayCommand _enterCommand;
public RelayCommand EnterCommand
{
    get
    {
        return _enterCommand ?? (_enterCommand = new RelayCommand(param =>
        {
            var point = (Point)param;
            test1.Content = "Mouse entered";
            // test2.Content = point.ToString();
        },
        param => true));
    }
}
```

And the attached properties (the 'nice' wrapper)...

```
public static class Hooks
{
    private static Dictionary<ContentControl, Action> _hash = new Dictionary<ContentControl, Action>();

    #region MouseMoveCommand

    public static ICommand GetMouseMoveCommand(ContentControl control) { return (ICommand)control.GetValue(MouseMoveCommandProperty); }
    public static void SetMouseMoveCommand(ContentControl control, ICommand value) { control.SetValue(MouseMoveCommandProperty, value); }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty MouseMoveCommandProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("MouseMoveCommand", typeof(ICommand), typeof(Hooks), new UIPropertyMetadata(null, OnMouseMoveCommandChanged));
    static void OnMouseMoveCommandChanged(DependencyObject depObj, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        ContentControl control = depObj as ContentControl;
        if (control != null && e.NewValue is ICommand)
            SetupMouseMove(control);
    }
    static void Instance_MouseMoveLL(object sender, WinHook.MouseLLMessageArgs e)
    {
    }
    static void OnAutoGeneratingColumn(ICommand command, object sender, DataGridAutoGeneratingColumnEventArgs e)
    {
        if (command.CanExecute(e)) command.Execute(e);
    }

    #endregion

    #region EnterCommand

    public static ICommand GetEnterCommand(ContentControl control) { return (ICommand)control.GetValue(EnterCommandProperty); }
    public static void SetEnterCommand(ContentControl control, ICommand value) { control.SetValue(EnterCommandProperty, value); }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty EnterCommandProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("EnterCommand", typeof(ICommand), typeof(Hooks), new UIPropertyMetadata(null, OnEnterCommandChanged));
    static void OnEnterCommandChanged(DependencyObject depObj, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        ContentControl control = depObj as ContentControl;
        if (control != null && e.NewValue is ICommand)
            SetupMouseMove(control);
    }

    #endregion

    #region LeaveCommand

    public static ICommand GetLeaveCommand(ContentControl control) { return (ICommand)control.GetValue(LeaveCommandProperty); }
    public static void SetLeaveCommand(ContentControl control, ICommand value) { control.SetValue(LeaveCommandProperty, value); }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty LeaveCommandProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("LeaveCommand", typeof(ICommand), typeof(Hooks), new UIPropertyMetadata(null, OnLeaveCommandChanged));
    static void OnLeaveCommandChanged(DependencyObject depObj, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        ContentControl control = depObj as ContentControl;
        if (control != null && e.NewValue is ICommand)
            SetupMouseMove(control);
    }

    #endregion

    static void SetupMouseMove(ContentControl control)
    {
        Action onmove;
        if (_hash.TryGetValue(control, out onmove) == false)
        {
            onmove = () =>
            {
                var entered = false;
                var moveCommand = control.GetValue(Hooks.MouseMoveCommandProperty) as ICommand;
                var enterCommand = control.GetValue(Hooks.EnterCommandProperty) as ICommand;
                var leaveCommand = control.GetValue(Hooks.LeaveCommandProperty) as ICommand;

                // hook is invoked on the 'caller thread' (i.e. your GUI one) so it's safe
                // don't forget to unhook and dispose / release it, handle unsubscribe for events
                WinHook.Instance.MouseMoveLL += (s, e) =>
                {
                    Point point = control.PointFromScreen(new Point(e.Message.Pt.X, e.Message.Pt.Y));

                    if (moveCommand != null && moveCommand.CanExecute(point))
                        moveCommand.Execute(point);

                    var newEntered = control.IsMouseInBounds(point); // don't use 'IsMouseOver'
                    if (newEntered != entered)
                    {
                        entered = newEntered;
                        if (entered)
                        {
                            if (enterCommand != null && enterCommand.CanExecute(point))
                                enterCommand.Execute(point);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            if (leaveCommand != null && leaveCommand.CanExecute(point))
                                leaveCommand.Execute(point);
                        }
                    }
                };
            };
            control.Loaded += (s, e) => onmove();
            _hash[control] = onmove;
        }
    }
    private static bool IsMouseInBounds(this ContentControl control, Point point)
    {
        var client = ((FrameworkElement)control.Content);
        Rect bounds = new Rect(0, 0, client.ActualWidth, client.ActualHeight);
        return bounds.Contains(point);
    }
}
```

And you could use [HookManager](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7294/Processing-Global-Mouse-and-Keyboard-Hooks-in-C) from the article.

Or the minimal hook code (mind that proper IDisoposable is required, exception handling etc.):

```
public sealed class WinHook : IDisposable
{
    public static readonly WinHook Instance = new WinHook();

    public const int WH_MOUSE_LL = 14;
    public const uint WM_MOUSEMOVE = 0x0200;

    public delegate void MouseLLMessageHandler(object sender, MouseLLMessageArgs e);
    public delegate int HookProc(int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", ExactSpelling = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    public static extern int GetCurrentThreadId();

    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall, SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern int SetWindowsHookEx(int idHook, HookProc lpfn, IntPtr hInstance, int threadId);

    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall, SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern bool UnhookWindowsHookEx(int idHook);

    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall, SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern int CallNextHookEx(int idHook, int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    public static extern IntPtr GetModuleHandle(string lpModuleName);

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct POINT
    {
        public int X;
        public int Y;
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public class MouseLLHookStruct
    {
        public POINT Pt;
        public uint mouseData;
        public uint flags;
        public uint time;
        public uint dwExtraInfo;
    }

    public class MouseLLMessageArgs : EventArgs
    {
        public bool IsProcessed { get; set; }
        public MouseLLHookStruct Message { get; private set; }
        public MouseLLMessageArgs(MouseLLHookStruct message) { this.Message = message; }
    }

    static IntPtr GetModuleHandle()
    {
        using (Process process = Process.GetCurrentProcess())
        using (ProcessModule module = process.MainModule)
            return GetModuleHandle(module.ModuleName);
    }

    public event MouseLLMessageHandler MouseMoveLL;

    int _hLLMouseHook = 0;
    HookProc LLMouseHook;

    private WinHook()
    {
        IntPtr hModule = GetModuleHandle();
        LLMouseHook = LowLevelMouseProc;
        _hLLMouseHook = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_MOUSE_LL, LLMouseHook, hModule, 0);
        if (_hLLMouseHook == 0) { } // "failed w/ an error code: {0}", new Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error()).Message
    }

    public void Release()
    {
        if (_hLLMouseHook == 0) return;
        int hhook = _hLLMouseHook;
        _hLLMouseHook = 0;
        bool ret = UnhookWindowsHookEx(hhook);
        if (ret == false) { } // "failed w/ an error code: {0}", new Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error()).Message
    }

    public int LowLevelMouseProc(int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
    {
        if (nCode >= 0 && lParam.ToInt32() > 0
            && wParam.ToInt32() == (int)WM_MOUSEMOVE)
        {
            MouseLLHookStruct msg = (MouseLLHookStruct)Marshal.PtrToStructure(lParam, typeof(MouseLLHookStruct));
            MouseLLMessageArgs args = new MouseLLMessageArgs(msg);
            if (MouseMoveLL != null)
                MouseMoveLL(this, args);
            if (args.IsProcessed)
                return -1; // return 1;
        }
        return CallNextHookEx(_hLLMouseHook, nCode, wParam, lParam);
    }
    // implement IDisposable properly and call `Release` for unmanaged resources / hook
    public void Dispose() { }
}
```

---

**Note:** global mouse hooks are notorious for performance issues. And you cannot use the local one (recommended but most of the time useless) - as it doesn't get outside mouse moves.

Also **avoid putting anything 'heavy' inside the event** - or anything that 'spawns off' from it. There is a limit actually on the time you can spend processing the event - or your hook will get removed, i.e. stop working. If you need to do some processing from the event, pop up a new thread and Invoke back.
My favorite solution is actually to give the hook its own thread and then events need to be invoked - but that's out of scope and a bit more complex (you need a 'pump' in there etc.).

**As to 'why' all this is necessary:**
I don't like speculating, but seems that events are throttled - and the critical 'one' is missed when 'crossing the border', something like that. Anyway, it's all about the mouse moves no matter how you look at it.

Comment: I edited in a simple `attached properties` wrapper for ease of use